# Adding a bridge on top of a bonded interface that have multiple ip?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux-networking, command-line-interface, bonding

I have a server that has three static IP addresses. I'd like to add a bridge to these settings. I tried to add the bridge this way but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
slaves eno1 eno2
bond-mode active-backup
bond-miimon 100
bond-primary eno1

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address x.x.x.108
  netmask 255.255.255.100
  gateway x.x.x.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2
  bridge_ports bond0
  bridge_stp on
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_maxwait 0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address x.x.x.108
  netmask 255.255.255.100

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address x.x.x.110
  netmask 255.255.255.100
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an obvious error here:

```
  bridge_ports bond_lan
```

You named your bond interface `bond0`, but mistyped it there as `bond_lan`.

```
  bridge_ports bond0
```

The other error is that you have added the IP addresses to the bond interface, but they have to be added to the bridge interface. Also change those to `br0`.

```
iface br0 inet static
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've edit my question and added your advice. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SeleenaDay Your netmask looks wrong too. Contact your network administrator to learn the correct IP addresses and netmask.